# Access Violation Reading Location 0x000000xx - c struct property - Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, struct, access-violation

As the title tells the story. Pasted below is the piece of code and all the dependencies. The error is strange to me because I am able to access the same variables in Watch window, and I can find no valid reason why I would get this error on runtime. Most of the questions with the same title I was able to find were related to null addresses being accessed, which is not the case here. 0X00000069 is the location which can not be accessed. I have also attached Watch window screenshot below.

```
typedef struct
{
    void  * variable;     // variable address
    char * signature;
    char name[30];
    char type[50];
}   GlobalVariable;

GlobalVariable VariableTable[] = 
{
    { &a, "int a = 7;", "a", "int"},
    { &ch, "char ch = 'a';", "ch", "char"},
    { NULL, NULL }
};

void PrintGlobalVariables()
{
    GlobalVariable * variable = VariableTable;
    int count = 0;
    while(variable->variable)
    {
        count++;
        variable++;
    }
    if(!count)
    {
        OutputDebugString("No global variables passed.\n");
        return;
    }
    int i = 0 ;
    variable = VariableTable;

    char       temp[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy(temp, "                                                             ");
    OutputDebugString("Global Variables = "); 
    while(variable->variable)
    {
        if(strcmp(trimwhitespace(variable->type),"int") == 0)
        {


            ////////THIS IS THE STATEMENT BELOW WHERE I AM GETTING ERROR
            wsprintf(temp, "%s=%ld",*(char *)variable->signature, *(long *)variable->variable);


        } else
        if(strcmp(trimwhitespace(variable->type),"char") == 0)
        {
            wsprintf(temp, "%s=%c", *(char *)variable->name, *(char *)variable->variable);
        }
        if((variable+1)->variable != NULL)
        {
            wsprintf(temp + strlen(temp), ",", "");
        }
        OutputDebugString(temp);
        variable++;

    }
    OutputDebugString("\n");
}
char *trimwhitespace(char *str)
{
    char *end;

    // Trim leading space
    while(isspace(*str)) str++;

    if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
        return str;

    // Trim trailing space
    end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;

    // Write new null terminator
    *(end+1) = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

[image: Watch Values]

Comment: Please post a **complete** program that we can compile and run for ourselves and watch crash.  With bugs like this, the root cause almost always turns out to be far away from the point where the problem manifests.  If possible also remove all use of non-ISO C library functions (e.g. replace all calls to `OutputDebugString` with `printf` or `puts`).

Comment: If you compiled this with a sane compiler, you'd get the pleasure of format-string checks, which would immediately show you the error.

Comment: @EOF I didn't get your comment.

Comment: @zwol on it........

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui: A good compiler would have yelled at you when you started adding casts and indirection operators at random.

Comment: Well, I am using Visual Studio 2008 with its own compiler options. @zwol

Comment: @zwol I have added a link to project in the post.

Comment: `*(char *)variable->signature`. What type does that give you? And what type does `%s` expect?

Comment: I know I didn't need to cast it, it gives me the string. %s expects string too.

Comment: I dont understand the downvote.

Comment: How can it give you a string? `signature` is a `char *`. So if you dereference it you will get a `char` not a string. That's even shown in your watch window. So of course the `wsprintf` will crash.

Comment: Thank you @kaylum. This is my first project in c in years after C#. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as one.

Comment: You are aware that when you pass `%s` to printf, it's expecting a **NULL terminated string**, which is absolutely **not** what you're passing to it. Why would you expect it to do anything else but blow up?

Comment: Yes @KenWhite the preceding * was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wsprintf(temp, "%s=%ld",*(char *)variable->signature, *(long *)variable->variable);
```

The `signature` field is a `char *`. Dereferencing it will give a `char`. But the `%s` format specifier requires a `char *`. The fix is to change that line by removing the dereference (and the cast is unnecessary too).

```
wsprintf(temp, "%s=%ld", variable->signature, *(long *)variable->variable);
```